# Laravel 5.3 Collective not installing

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.3, laravelcollective

I'm learning how to work with forms but I got an error on the first try when I tried simple html code.

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="{{url('/painel/produtos/store')}}">
```

With this code I got this error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

So I searched around and find out that people use this code instead

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/painel/produtos/store')) }}
```

And I got a new error which is `Class 'Form' not found` so i searched and found that I would need Laravel Collective but when I try to install it it gives me this error:

```
  [UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse version constraint :5.3.0: Invalid version string ":5.3.0"
```

So I dont know what to do more.

Comment: Can you share the edit you made to your `composer.json`?

Comment: I didn't made any edit on composer.json

Comment: And where did you get that error message about that version constraint? You tagged your question with `composer-php`, so I assumed there would be a problem with installing a package

Comment: But reading your post a second time, I think you got the method restriction wrong. Have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html#adding-http-method-requirements

Comment: This is the right code to use: `{!! Form::open(['url' => '/painel/produtos/store']) !!}`

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try this.

But the project has abandoned.

`composer require "laravelcollective/html"::"^5.3.0"`

Comment: Hi Gabriel, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you explain in your answer in more detail what that line of code does, where it belongs, and how it answers the original question?